# Is there a way of implementing shades of colors in treemap for childs of specific parent

Tags: javascript, highcharts, treemap

I have a jsfiddle with 3 parents ( Banana, apple, orange ) and when treemap renders for example Banana has objects with values ( Rick, Anne, Susane ) and what it renders is same color ( yellow in this example ) and my goal is for example if value of that object is 10 to be yellow with no blurred to yellow, and if value of that object is 1 to be almost white with hint of yellow.
Is there an algorithm that handles that ? I am quite sure that this is already known request from people.

For now I managed to create in one fiddle those parents with childs, and in other I managed to produce different versions of shades of that specific color

this is data of parents and kids
[image]

```
{
            id: 'A',
            name: 'Apples',
            color: "#EC2500"
        }, {
            id: 'B',
            name: 'Bananas',
            color: "#ECE100"
        }, {
            id: 'O',
            name: 'Oranges',
            color: '#EC9800'
        }, {
            name: 'Anne',
            parent: 'A',
            value: 5
        }, {
            name: 'Rick',
            parent: 'A',
            value: 3
        }, {
            name: 'Peter',
            parent: 'A',
            value: 4
        }, {
            name: 'Anne',
            parent: 'B',
            value: 4
        }
```

and this is result that I would like to implement into fiddle above with different shades of yellow, red and orange
[image]

```
{
    colorAxis: {
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: '#FFFF33'
        // maxColor:Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'treemap',
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        data: [{
            name: 'Rick',
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Anne',
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Susane',
            value: 4,
            colorValue: 3
        }, {
            name: 'Peter',
            value: 3,
            colorValue: 4
        }, {
            name: 'E',
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 5
        }, {
            name: 'F',
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 6
        }, {
            name: 'G',
            value: 1,
            colorValue: 7
        }]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
    }
}
```

This is the fiddle with shades of yellow
https://jsfiddle.net/bpc7fd49/1/
and this is fiddle where I am trying to implement those shades instead of having only one version of yellow red or orange color
https://jsfiddle.net/7z5ngLva/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find an answer

```
stops = [
            [0.25, '#EC2500'],
            [0.5, '#ECE100'],
            [0.75, '#EC9800'],
            [1, '#9EDE00']
        ],
        distance = stops[1][0] - stops[0][0],
        modifiedStops = [];

    $.each(stops, function (i, stop) {
        modifiedStops.push([stop[0] - distance - 0.001, '#ffffff']);
        modifiedStops.push(stop);
        modifiedStops.push([stop[0] + 0.001, stop[1]]);
    });
```

whole fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4egy85fw/

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use the `colorAxis` form `heatmap`, you can calculate the colors for points by using the `tweenTo` internal method:

```
(function(H) {
    var treemapProto = Highcharts.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype,
        minVal,
        maxVal,
        values,
        children;

    Highcharts.wrap(treemapProto, 'translate', function(proceed) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        this.values = {};

        this.points.forEach(function(point) {
            children = point.node.children;

            if (children.length) {
                minVal = null;
                maxVal = null;

                children.forEach(function(child) {
                    minVal = minVal ? Math.min(minVal, child.val) : child.val;
                    maxVal = maxVal ? Math.max(maxVal, child.val) : child.val;
                });

                this.values[point.id] = {
                    minVal: minVal,
                    maxVal: maxVal,
                    minColor: point.minColor,
                    maxColor: point.maxColor
                };
            } else {
                values = this.values[point.parent];

                point.color = H.color(values.minColor).tweenTo(
                    H.color(values.maxColor),
                    (point.value - values.minVal) / (values.maxVal - values.minVal)
                );
            }
        }, this);
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b1k5whcv/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

Comment: Hey ppotaczek, thank you for answer, your solution works only for version 6+ of highcharts, but not on for example 4. Thanks for contribution nonetheless !